# onEditor action not working when trying to respond to the tick on the android numeric soft keyboard

Tags: android

I have an EditText in my app with an input type of number:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answerText"
    style="@style/GeneralTextStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/question"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equals"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:text="ans"/>
```

So when the EditText has focus the numeric keyboard is displayed.  I am trying to repond to the user pressing the tick button after supplying a value in the EditText but I can't get it to work.

[image]

I've tried the following code which I've put inside the onCreate method but it isn't working:

```
    answerGivenText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add the

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

attribute to your edittext.

Answer (score 0):

That code is exactly what you need, but you are not doing anything inside it, you're just intercepting the click and returning true, indicating that you handled it to other listeners on the stack.

You would do whatever it is you want to do when the user clicks the tick in the

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
```

section. And turn on the DONE action in your layout. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, the code is intentionally blank at the moment, I just wanted to make sure that I could respond to a user clicking tick first.  Thankyou to @Ahmed Happa and yourself for the answers